# Driver program to connect Fatek PLC and OPC UA server

Tags: python, plc, opc

I have created one OPC-UA server as well as client. Now I want to connect OPC-UA server to Fatek PLC but I don't know how to do that. Can someone help me?

A little driver program/script will be much appreciated, as I don't want to use existing softwares for connecting PLC and OPC-UA server. Code will be much appreciated preferably in python.

Below is the OPC UA Server code for reference :

```
from opcua import Server
import datetime
from random import randint
import time

server = Server()
port = "4840"
url = "opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:4840"
server.set_endpoint(url)
name = 'OPCUA_SIMULATION_SERVER'
addspace = server.register_namespace(name)
node = server.get_objects_node()
Param = node.add_object(addspace, "Parameters")
Temp = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Temperature", 0)
Press = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Pressure", 0)
Time = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Time", 0)
Temp.set_writable()
Press.set_writable()
Time.set_writable()
server.start()
print("Server started at {}".format(url))
print(addspace)
while True:
    Temperature = randint(10,50)
    Pressure = randint(200,999)
    TIME = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(Temperature, Pressure, TIME)
    Temp.set_value(Temperature)
    Press.set_value(Pressure)
    Time.set_value(TIME)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: This is a very broad question, what steps or code have you tried or websites you have visited (apart from StackOverflow)?

Comment: Jim, I have visited a number of websites(even tutorials on youtube), but they all talk about softwares provided by PLC vendors. I took help of one youtube tutorial for writing OPC UA server code.

Comment: What is the protocol of your PLC for PLC - PC communication?